# CodeFirst access property of another virtual property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following models (simplified) used inside a CodeFirst scaffolded ASP.NET MVC site:

```
Public Tax
{
   public int ID {get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set; }
   public decimal Rate {get; set; } 
}

Public OrderLine
{
   public int ID {get; set; }

   public int TaxID {get; set; }
   public virtual Tax Tax {get; set; }

   public decimal Quantity {get; set; }
   public decimal Price {get; set; }

   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
   public decimal Amount
   {
      get { return Quantity * Price; }
      set { }
   }

   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
   public decimal AmountWithTax
   {
      get { return Amount + (Amount * Tax.Rate / 100); }
      set { }
   }
}
```

`Amount` and `AmountWithTax` are calculated properties and I don't need them inside the UI but I need them to be saved inside the database. The problem is that when I create a new `OrderLine` the property `Tax` is null (`TaxID` is filled and contains the int value) so `AmountWithTax` throw an exception.

How can I access `Rate` property?

Steps to reproduce:

Add the two models to a standard ASP.NET MVC EF project, create the scaffolded Items using right click -> Add  > New Scaffolded Item... -> MVC5 ... with EntityFramework -> and select the model inside Model Class.

Visual Studio will generate the controller and the views, if an OrderLine is created by the Create view, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown on the property Tax.Rate because Tax is null

Comment: Show more code. How do you create a new `OrderLine`? Shouldn't you use a ViewModel as opposed to an entity model? If you don't want that, can't you set `newOrderline.Tax = db.Taxes.Find(newOrderline.TaxID)`? When does `AmountWithTax` throw?

Comment: `OrderLine` is created using the scaffolded views, so the code is the standard one generated, and the HttpPost method `public ActionResult Create` is not called because the null exception happens before (so after I click create I get the exception)

Comment: Please explain all the relevant steps to reproduce it in your question. Include your `Create` action method code. Also mention the full exception.

Comment: You're missing the action method. You're still not explaining _when_ and _where_ the exception occurs.

Comment: the exception happens inside the get method of the property AmountWithTax. My requirement is: when an orderline is created the AmountWithTax needs to be calculated using the Rate value of the Tax, is this possible using CodeFirst?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewModels, not Entity Models. Using a view model that maps the properties you want to the entity model should fix it for you.

If you don't want that, you can exclude the properties from being bound as explained in [How do you exclude properties from binding when calling UpdateModel()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332594/how-do-you-exclude-properties-from-binding-when-calling-updatemodel):

```
[Bind(Exclude="Amount,AmountWithTax")]
```

This will let the model binder ignore those properties, causing their `set` to not be called.

By the way, the setters of `Amount` and `AmountWithTax` will cause a `StackOverflowException`, as they are assigning a value to themselves. You can also make them read-only by simply removing the `set`.

Comment: the problem is that the exception is thrown inside the get, not on the set. I updated my source code, for the Amount property, the empty set gives the expected result, but for AmountWithTax the Tax is null and I don't know where I can fill it

Comment: That's why I asked you twice now to post the full exception and its stack trace in your question. The problem is not Entity Framework and it isn't Code First.

Comment: The style `public int TaxID {get; set; }  public virtual Tax Tax {get; set; }` is because it's a 1:N relationship to be used inside EntityFramework CodeFirst, I can choose a value for Tax but there is a way to use the properties of the Tax object?

Comment: I explained how to do so in my [first comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023054/codefirst-access-property-of-another-virtual-property/31023842?noredirect=1#comment50071233_31023054).