# How to ignore custom model binder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model binder in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new StringModelBinder());
```

And I have a model in which I want to ignore the binder for one of string properties:

```
public class MyModel
{
    ...
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For instance StringModelBinder trims my string. But I don't want to trim StringProp. How can I ignore the binder in such case?

EDITED:
I am not looking for a solution to trim a string. I'm looking for a solution to ignore trimming for some string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: Best way to trim strings after data entry.  Should I create a custom model binder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custo)

Comment: Maybe create  a custom attribute, put it on this property, and change your custom model binder to ignore properties with this attribute. You may find interesting infos here (even if that's the opposite) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186969/custom-model-binder-for-a-property

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, yes, I thought about a custom attribute. But I'm looking for a better solution. May be something out of the box.

Comment: My bet would be also with @RaphaëlAlthaus since you want for "some" strings and not others. It's a simple solution to implement and conceptually simple to understand. Even DontTrimAttribute would be fine and concize.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332594/how-do-you-exclude-properties-from-binding-when-calling-updatemodel

Comment: @SelectDistinct, it ignores binding at all. I want to ignore only custom model binder.