# How do I tell Spring to exclude binding an object property?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller method that has two object params:

```
@GetMapping
public List<Car> getCars(BlueBookCar blueBookCar, AutoTraderCar autoTraderCar)
```

Both `BlueBookCar` and `AutoTraderCar` have a field named `id`. I want the query param name `id` in an HTTP GET request to be bound only to the `BlueBookCar` instance.

For example, the following:

```
http://localhost/cars?id=123
```

Should result in `blueBookCar` having an `id` equal to 123. The `autoTraderCar` id should be null. Instead, Spring sets both objects with an `id` of 123.

How can I tell Spring to exclude binding `id` for the `autoTraderCar`? Other `autoTraderCar` fields that have names matching query param names should be set (as Spring normally does).

**Update**

I meant to note that:

1. I do not want HTTP clients to be aware of the existence of two types of cars, `BlueBookCar` & `AutoTraderCar`
2. All properties except `id` are different between the two types of car. It's possible that later other properties may overlap.
3. I do not want to create a third class with the set of properties from both classes for maintenance reasons and because the classes have relationships.

ASP.NET MVC supports property binding exclusions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8332917/1706691. Does Spring support this?

Comment: why make autoTraderCar a method parameter in the first place ? you can have 1 object gets the data and then do whatever needed inside the controller

Comment: @AhmedNabil - I have fields in `AutoTraderCar` that are not present in `BlueBookCar`. Only `id` is present in both classes. I do not want to create a third class that has all properties of the two classes.

Comment: FYI - This is possible using ASP.NET MVC. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8332917/1706691. Does Spring not support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@InitBinder` which allows you to access `WebDataBinder` for customising how to bind the data from the http request to a particular parameter object in the controller method.

In your case , adding the following should solve your problem :

```java
@Controller
public class CarController {


    @InitBinder("autoTraderCar")
    public void initAutoTraderCarDataBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Car> getCars(BlueBookCar blueBookCar, AutoTraderCar autoTraderCar){

    }

}
```